# Debian Installer asks for tasksel confirmation

Tags: debian, preseed

The preseed.cfg file I included in "debian-8.3.0-amd64-netinst.iso" does its job very well, except when confirming software selection.

I removed the old "tasksel tasksel/first multiselect ..." then added the following line:

```
tasksel tasksel/desktop multiselect lxde
```

It works. But the installer asks for confirmation. These lines don't work:

```
d-i tasksel-desktop/confirm boolean true
d-i tasksel/confirm boolean true
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct task name is `lxde-desktop`, so the line should be:

```
tasksel tasksel/desktop multiselect lxde-desktop
```